# How to pass role information while creating an user in Oracle cloud app using Create User API

Tags: rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-apps, oracle-rest-data-services

I am using below endpoint to send JSON request body to create an user in oracle cloud application https://servername.fa.us2.oraclecloud.com/hcmRestApi/scim/Users

I am able to create an user, If I don't pass option "roles" json array element in request.
But I do pass it with roles that are existing in system.
I am getting below error-

```
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "description": "You can't use the roles attribute in the payload. (ASE-4335076)",
            "code": "400"
        }
    ]
}
```

Request-

```
{
 "schemas":[
  "urn:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
 ],
 "roles": [
   {
   "id": "E3A40F5AB13D90D7E040F00AC6466664"
   }
 ],
 "name":{
  "familyName":"Manik",
  "givenName":"Jones"
 },
 "active":true,
 "userName":"KTMANIK_OPERATIONS",
 "password":"Welcome123",
 "emails":[
  {
   "primary":true,
   "value":"ktmanikk@oracle.com",
   "type":"W"
  }
 ],
 "displayName":"Manik Jones",
 "externalId":"554434"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this page should address the issue you are experiencing - https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/20b/farca/Add_a_Role_to_a_User.html